# How to check "Automatic date and time" is enabled or not?

Tags: android, datetime

I need to check whether "Automatic date and time" in the android device is enabled or not. If it is not enabled I need to display the popup that it is not enabled.

Is it possible to achieve. If possible, how to check enabled or not ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no public method in the SDK to do this.

Answer (score 54):

[Link for API 17 and above](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AUTO_TIME)

```
android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

[Link for API 16 and below](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AUTO_TIME)

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

Comment: But just for API 17 and above.

Comment: a quick search reveals that before that, `android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME` was the way to go.

Comment: Working on 7.1.2

Answer (score 40):

```
public static boolean isTimeAutomatic(Context c) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    } else {
        return android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I would just like to point out that it is possible to cheat (I just did it on a Samsung Galaxy S4, Android 5.0.1):

- Disable auto time
- Disconnect from the internets (airplane mode, no wifi etc...)
- reboot phone (otherwise the real time is retrieved)
- set auto time on

Done today:

Unix time: 1129294173

Date: **14102005**024933

is automatic? **1** (using android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0))

And today definitely isn't Oct 14, 2005

Comment: It is true, just find 5min ago, this is the reason i am here :) Is there any session id that i can use to track if reboot occurred?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Global.AUTO_TIME) == 1)
{
    // Enabled
}
else
{
    // Disabed
}
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Check is Auto Time or Zone is Enabled ? (**Kotlin**)

```
fun isAutoTimeEnabled(activity: Activity) =
    Settings.Global.getInt(activity.contentResolver, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME) == 1

fun isAutoTimeZoneEnabled(activity: Activity) =
    Settings.Global.getInt(activity.contentResolver, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE) == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin you can use

```
fun isTimeAutomatic(c: Context): Boolean {
return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    Settings.Global.getInt(c.contentResolver, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1
} else {
    Settings.System.getInt(c.contentResolver, Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1
}}
```