# Android: How to verify if the date time provided by the system is correct?

Tags: android, offline

How do we verify if the date/time provided by the Android system to our app is correct?

We cannot use network activity, we have tried doing it using a server, and it's working nicely. But need to check if there is a speedy way we can do some offline checking on the phone's provided date/time?

Comment: I have that problem in android and at the end I use the scenario explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449737/how-can-i-get-correct-current-date-and-time-for-android-device-while-device-is-o

Answer (score 6):

Buddies, figured out the answer

First we need to check if Automatic Date/Time is Enabled or not from here,
[How to check "Automatic date and time" is enabled or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075446/how-to-check-automatic-date-and-time-is-enabled-or-not)

If enabled, that can mean the date is be correct (mostly)

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is sometimes online you could cache the last date and compare it.
If the [Auto update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075446/how-to-check-automatic-date-and-time-is-enabled-or-not) is enable, I think you could trust it.
Else, you could do some ultra ugly stuff to vedify date is not total corrupted.
I don't think there is a stright way to do this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't a built in API to check whether the system time is correct or not by comparing it to a server for example. However, it should be simple to implement a query that checks a server to check the current time and compare it to the system time.

Comment: The challenge with this approach is that the time used to get the response from the server to the device should be taken into consideration and I find it hard to determine , I'm open to hear anyone who can help with this challenge . ` TimeOnDevice = TimeOnServer + TimeUsedFromServerToDevie ` (This is what I'm talking about )