# How can I get correct current date and time for android device while device is offline

Tags: java, android, date, time

I create an android app and in this app, users can save some tasks. Those tasks are saved in device and when user go online, tasks will be sync to server.
I need to know the correct date and time when user save the task. Codes like `Calendar.getInstance()` or `new Date()` return device time and if device time was not correct, task save with wrong date. It's important for this app to work offline. And Because of bushiness of this app, It is possible that user change device time in purpose.

Comment: You need a server and an endpoint that returns you the correct date as device can only give you the device time.

Comment: @Varundroid So in that case if user was offline, he cant save the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**So I end up with a scenario for which a user at most will connect to internet just once per every device reboot.**

I try to connect to a NTP server when user boots (`BOOT_COMPLETED BroadcastReceiver`) or Network states changed (`CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and WIFI_STATE_CHANGED BroadcastReceiver`) and then I store that date and `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` in the database. After that when ever I want to have the correct date, I just get new `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and calculate the difference of this value and the elapsedRealtime value from database and add that difference to date that I store in database.

Answer (score 0):

For others who have the same problem, there is a powerful library named TrueTime. To use it add it to your project dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:3.5'
```

in onCreate method of your `Application` class [if you use RxJava]:

```
TrueTimeRx.build()
        .withLoggingEnabled(true)
        .withSharedPreferencesCache(this)
        .initializeRx("1.us.pool.ntp.org")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(date -> Log.v("TrueTime", "TrueTime initialized, time: " + date),
                throwable -> Log.e("TrueTime", "TrueTime exception: ", throwable)
        );
```

And for use:

```
if (TrueTimeRx.isInitialized()) {
    Date reliableDateNow = TrueTimeRx.now();
    // use the current date
}
```

How it works:

It uses NTP protocol to initialize datetime from network only once. And calculates datetime using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(). If device is rebooted it will reinit the time using specified NTP servers.

Github repository:
https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android/