# How to check if Automatic Time Zone check is enabled or not in android

Tags: android, timezone

I need to know how can I check if automatic time zone is checked and enabled in android device programatically .

I got to know for Automatic date and time via this question :

[Automatic Time and Date Check in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075446/how-to-check-automatic-date-and-time-is-enabled-or-not)

But now need to know for Automatic Timezone .

Comment: The question is different

Comment: Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use [AUTO_TIME_ZONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AUTO_TIME_ZONE) instead of AUTO_TIME that you see in the the linked question.

Answer (score -1):

**This function returns 1(true) if the time zone is set to automatic else it returns 0(false) if it is not set to automatic time zone.**

```
private boolean isTimeZoneAutomatic(Context c) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                return Settings.Global.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, 0) == 1;
            } else {
                return android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, 0) == 1;
            }
}
```