# Android make app use automatic time zone and prevent user from using manual time mode

Tags: java, android, timezone, whatsapp

In my android application I want the app to use date and time provided by the network. User should not be able to use manual time mode. Whenever user switches to manual mode time zone app should throw a message similar to whatsapp "user phone date is inaccurate" and prevent the user from using  the app further. Any complete example?

Comment: You just call the API. check from the API.

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine - Is it possible on app side?

Comment: If you want to ensure ```Automatic date & time``` is always switched on, you may take a look in this previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075446/how-to-check-automatic-date-and-time-is-enabled-or-not

Comment: Related: [How can I get the "network" time, (from the "Automatic" setting called "Use network-provided values"), NOT the time on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw) Search for more.

Comment: @Enowneb I implemented code from the link you gave but it is checking only when the activity is loaded. So user can maniplulate the time ..Is there a way where it can be checked continuously if automatic time zone is selected?

Comment: Are you implementing the checking in ```onCreate()```? Is there any chance to do that in ```onResume()``` if the ```Activity``` is not destroyed?

Comment: @Enowneb - yes was using in onCreate()

Comment: @Abm Try to move your checking into ```onResume()```. After user has left the ```Activity```, go to ```Setting```, switch off ```Automatic date & time```, and return back to the ```Activity```, ```onResume()``` is called. Therefore you can put your checking there to guarantee it will run every time when the ```Activity``` is on screen.

Comment: @Enowneb - onResume() is working