Detect whether Date & Time is set automatically or manually in Flutter
Is their any way or plugin available to detect whether the device Date & time is set automatically or user has entered manually
i can get proper current Date time with
await NTP.now(timeout: Duration(seconds: 3)); 
But i need to know Device Date & Time is manually set or not
Thanks in advance

There is no way of achieving this. Android and iOS don't provide such APIs.

Flutter does not provide a built-in way to directly determine if the device date and time are set automatically or manually but you can activate this functionality in native android.

Used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076554/15195881 and got the data. with the help of MethodChannel.

If you're concerned about the actual time, use the package:ntp.  If it needs to operate even when you're off network, there's no way to do it, as others have said.
